# Mass adding members of another group on Telegram to a group

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

[Python] I use a bot that scraps a list of users from one Telegram group, saves them to CSV, and then invites them to my group. However, after a few-dozen-dozen members, I get a temporary block, as a result of which I can no longer add more users to groups for a specified time limit.

I know there are tons of bots that can do the above steps without such problems. How to get around it? Greater gap between adding users? Something else?

I am using the telethon library.

Comment: Are you using `username` for adding members or  the `user_id` ?